# How to solve the following PDE for A and B?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have a PDE of the form
$$
\frac{dA}{dt}- A(t) \frac{dB}{dt} x^2 - 2 \gamma x^2 A(t)B(t) - \sigma^2 A(t)B(t) + 2 \sigma^2 x^2 A(t) B(t)^2 = 0.
$$
where $\sigma,\gamma$ are constants (I believe we can just set them to $1$ to simplify) and $A,B$ are functions of $t$.  What methods can we use to solve for the forms of $A(t)$ and $B(t)$?

Comment: what about $x$? should it be $t$?

Comment: No it really should be $x$. One idea I had was to equate the coefficients for the $x^2$ terms to get $-\frac{dA/dt}{A(t)} + \sigma^2 B(t) = 0$ and $dB/dt - 2 \sigma^2 B(t)^2 = -2 \gamma B(t)$. But not sure what that gets me toward a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the equation 
$$
\frac{dA}{dt}- A(t) \frac{dB}{dt} x^2 - 2 \gamma x^2 A(t)B(t) - \sigma^2 A(t)B(t) + 2 \sigma^2 x^2 A(t) B(t)^2 
$$
holds for all $x$, then it holds for $x=0$ and therefore from one side
$$
\frac{dA}{dt}=  \sigma^2 A(t) B(t)
$$
which gives
$$
\frac{dA}{A}=  \sigma^2  B(t)dt
\Rightarrow\ln A=\sigma^2 \int B(t)dt\\\Rightarrow
A(t)=\exp\left({\sigma^2 \int B(t)dt}\right)
$$

From the other side 
$$\frac{dB}{dt}  = 2 \gamma  B(t)  + 2 \sigma^2   B(t)^2 $$
so $$B(t)=-\frac{\gamma  e^{C \gamma +2 \gamma  t}}{\sigma ^2 e^{C \gamma +2 \gamma  t}\pm 1}$$
where $C$ is the integration constant to be determined using initial condition for $B$.

Finally, integration gives
$$A(t)=\exp\left({\sigma^2 \int B(t)dt}\right)=
\widetilde C e^{
-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(1\pm\sigma ^2 e^{C \gamma +2 \gamma  t}\right)
}=
\frac{\widetilde C}{\sqrt{1\pm\sigma ^2 e^{c_1 \gamma +2 \gamma  t}}}
$$
where $\widetilde C $ is an integration constant, to be determined from initial condition for $A$.

Comment: I took a different approach (inspired by my comment above) and have some slightly different solutions. Are these solutions unique? I found $B(t) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2 /2 + c_1 e^{2\gamma t}}$ and $A(t) = c_2 \frac{c_1 e^{2\gamma t}}{c_1 e^{2\gamma t} + \sigma^2 / \gamma}$ for constants $c_1 ,c_2$. Could this be another possible set of solutions?

Comment: your B doesn't solve the equation. Regarding the uniqueness, due to non linearity of the equation for $B$ which has $B^2$ you have two solutions - I will update it in a moment with a $\pm$ at the correct place.